# Usage of header location in PHP

Tags: php

Can I use relative paths in using

```
header("location: http://something.com/someotherthing");
```

in PHP

Comment: @j0k: Not every question is worth the edit. But often worth the downvote.

Comment: See TFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @hakre and sometimes both ? :-)

Comment: @j0k: Well, it's always nice to make this site a better place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 ) says the location header must be set to an absolute path, but most clients would still work with relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

The [***standard***](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) is that you should use an absolute path.

Using relative paths is incorrect according to the standard, but  most popular browsers will accept a relative URL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location#Relative_URL_example

Answer (score 0):

The path "http://something.com/something" is actually an **absolute** path and not a **relative** path. And yes you can use both a relative or an absolute path.